# Trying to get the name of the currently running function in ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, built-in

I have a function that I would like to call and have it return the name of the function it was called from. Here is the function:

```
def get_pos
  func = __method__.to_s
  puts "You are in #{func}"
end
```

I understand that `__method__` returns the name of the method it is currently being executed in.

I am trying to call `get_pos()` from `test` and this is the output I want to get:

```
def test
  get_pos
end

You are in test
```

Instead I get the following

```
You are in get_pos
```

I understand why this is happening. Since `__method__` is located inside the getpos function it returns the name of that function.

I know that if i make the following change and pass `__method__` as an argument to the function, I'll get the expected result. Which is:

```
def get_pos(method)
  puts "You are in #{method}"
end

def test
  get_pos(__method__.to_s)
end

You are in test
```

The code has been simplified but is part of functionality in a logger where I want to be able to dump data about the current location in the code to a log and know exactly what module,class,function I am in.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this than passing `__method__` as a parameter to the function each time?

Comment: _"[...] and this is the output I get"_ – don't you mean "this is the output I want"?

Comment: @Stefan: Correct, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use `__callee__` from Kernel object?

I refactored your code:

```
def current
  puts __callee__
end

def test_caller
  current
end

test_caller
```

Which outputs `current` in this case.

There are all sorts of interesting methods in the `Kernel Object`. I recommend to take a look to the API [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__).

Comment: In this example, `__callee__` and `__method__` return the same value. The OP wants the method to return the name of the method it was called from, not its own name.

Comment: The only difference between `__method__` and `__callee__` is _they work differently for aliases_. Since this answer does not mention aliases at all, and even more, it adds zero value to what the OP had already, I doubt I understand how it could get upvoted 3 times and even be chosen _as a correct answer_. The answer by @Stefan is correct, btw.

Comment: I'll remove the answer if the answer got unaccepted, I misread.

Comment: Who knows? Maybe the OP wants something else :-)

Comment: I reread again, and he actually wants what his method is calling, using `__method__` but in a cleaner way, he doesn't want the stack, he wants the current method without sending a parameter, which is achieved with `__callee__`, probably that's why he accepted my answer.

Comment: Specifically quoting "The code has been simplified but is part of functionality in a logger where I want to be able to dump data about the current location in the code to a log and know exactly what module,class,function I am in.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this than passing __method__ as a parameter to the function each time?"

Comment: @RandallValenciano, following your example, what OP actually want is to print `test_caller` instead of `current`. Since `__method__` and `__callee__` are equivalent (i.e. return the exactly same values) in your examples, your solution provides no advantage over OPs attempts.

Comment: @RandallValenciano I think the OP wants the logger method (`get_pos`) to print information about the calling method (`test`), in particular its name, i.e. "test".

Comment: Yes guys, you're right, I apologize. I guess I got confused by the question. If this get unaccepted I would delete the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`caller_locations`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations) which returns an array of [`Thread::Backtrace::Location`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html) instances: (starting at index 1 by default, excluding the current method)

```
def foo
  caller_locations.map(&:base_label)
end

def bar
  foo
end

def baz
  bar
end

baz
#=> ["bar", "baz", "<main>"]
```

So `foo` was called from `bar` which was called from `baz` which was called in `<main>`.